# Upgrading Rails: What am I to do with new_framework_defaults file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am upgrading from rails 5.1 to 5.2.
I did `bundle update rails` (plus some dependencies) and `rails app:update`.
Now i have the file `initializers/new_framework_defaults_5_2.rb`, with all lines are commented out.

I am not sure what I need to do now. My app works normally, so I guess, with all lines are commented out I am already on all new defaults. Then I do not need that file, right?

Suppose I run into errors, the values set in the files are the new defaults? So I would uncomment, maybe flip the boolean and try to find out what caused the error?

thank you for your help

Answer (score 65, accepted):

(Having just gone through a 4.2 to 5.2 Rails upgrade, I'll write a more complete answer.)

### Rails 5.0

Starting with Rails 5, the Rails team [decided to generate an initializer](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/25184#issuecomment-222454583),  `config/initializers/new_framework_defaults.rb`, that contained values for new configuration defaults.  This file is generated for both new (`rails new`) Rails 5.0 applications and applications updated (`rake app:update`) to Rails 5.0, although the contents [differ](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/5-0-stable/railties/lib/rails/generators/rails/app/templates/config/initializers/new_framework_defaults.rb.tt) between new and updated apps.

For new projects, it contains defaults for Rails 5.0.

For updated projects, it contains defaults for the *previous version*.  The intent is that your application will run with the same defaults it had before, and you can toggle/update one at a time during your upgrade.

### Rails 5.1 and 5.2

After some shortcomings of this mechanism [became apparent](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/23589) (mostly related to the execution of initializers in lexical order), Rails 5.1 [made some changes](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/4183ee882055f997fe61804ba43ee4c168b2477c) to it.

[A new method](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/375a4143cf5caeb6159b338be824903edfd62836/railties/lib/rails/application/configuration.rb#L65), `#load_defaults`, has been added to `Rails.application.config`.  The new framework defaults initializer is versioned, e.g., `new_framework_defaults_5_1.rb`, and it is only generated during an update, not for a new application.

Unlike the `new_framework_defaults.rb` from Rails 5.0, settings in the `new_framework_defaults_5_x.rb` files are (almost) all commented-out.  They are the new defaults.  You can go through each of them, uncomment the setting, and test your application.  If your application runs correctly on the new defaults, you can discard the `new_framework_defaults_5_x.rb` file and bump the value in `config/application.rb` to the current version, i.e., change `config.load_defaults 5.1` to `config.load_defaults 5.2` if you were updating to Rails 5.2.

It's possible there is a setting for which you don't want the new default.  If I wanted to make such a setting permanent, I'd probably move it into `config/application.rb` somewhere below the `load_defaults` call for all environments, or in the appropriate `config/environments/*.rb` file(s) for environment-specific configurations.

### Summary

It seems to me like the `config/initializers/new_framework_defaults*.rb` files should not exist after successfully completing an upgrade.  They're just there to help highlight changes and aid upgrading from one version to the next.

Comment: I think at least the "most recent" new_framework_defaults*.rb IS intended to remain after the upgrade. It provides a way to set the desired value of the various defaults.